# What does this syntax mean in Java?

Tags: java, android, foreach, removeall

I have been programming small programs as a practice, and I have found the following syntax

```
Values.removeIf (element -> element == "D");
```

I understand, that in my opinion it will eliminate all the elements that contain, s "D" but why this "`element -> element`"?

good day

Comment: This is a lambda expression.

Comment: it is called a lambda expression. look it up on the internet. Also, you don't compare String with `==`.

Comment: Voting to close since the OP is asking for terminology in order to do further research.